# iOS 11 getting visibleHeight and contentInset from a UITableView or UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4

**Pre iOS 10**

if I wanted to get the visible height of a table or scroll view, I had to subtract the top and bottom inset from the height of the tableview

```
let tableView = ....
let height = tableView.frame.size.height - tableView.contentInset.top - tableView.contentInset.bottom
```

**iOS 11**

Unfortunately on iOS 11 suing the above method, I was am not getting the correct value.

After some debugging I realised that the top inset was 0.0, instead of the height of my navigation bar.

Answer (score 7):

**iOS 11 and UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior**

I am not getting the correct contentInset, as iOS 11 introduced UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior. More information can be found on the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior

Since UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior was introduced, we have to take into account the **adjustedContentInset** property and add it to the contentInset.

The above code has to be updated to the following:

```
let visibleHeigh: CGFloat
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
  visibleHeight = tableView.frame.size.height - (tableView.contentInset.top + tableView.adjustedContentInset.top) - (tableView.contentInset.bottom + tableView.adjustedContentInset.bottom)
} else {
  visibleHeight = tableView.frame.size.height - tableView.contentInset.top - tableView.contentInset.bottom
}
```

Comment: The docs for `adjustedContentInset` say "The safe area insets are then added to the values in the contentInset property to obtain the final value of this property." Which to me suggests we should be using `adjustedContentInset` for final values.

Comment: I noticed that this does not work for the top inset in practise. You have to add them. Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 7):

if you want the content inset of the scroll view to be unaffected by the "adjustedContentInset", you can disable this unpredictable behavior with the following code:

```
// obj-c
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
  [tableView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
}

// swift
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```